# Error 500 en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plesk

Tengo un error con la página de inicio de mi sitio en wordpress, el problema pasa solo en la página de inicio por defecto y solo cuando estoy logueado como administrador, tengo una plantilla instalada llamada korsel template.

Ese error solo se produce para administradores logueados y solo para la página que esté anclada al inicio, si la quito entonces si me deja modificarla.

```
Server Error 500 Internal Server Error The server encountered an
internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your
request. Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time
the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have
caused the error. More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.
```

LOG

```
[Mon Jan 09 21:06:39.435976 2023] [:error] [pid 197758:tid 140663358203648] [client 2.155.79.158:0] [client 2.155.79.158] ModSecurity: Output filter: Response body too large (over limit of 1048576, total not specified). [hostname "tallersantos.com"] [uri "/index.php"] [unique_id "Y7xzziwAC3s7JAB6Uw4toQAAAEo"]
    [Mon Jan 09 21:06:39.436428 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 197758:tid 140663358203648] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 2.155.79.158:0] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (passing brigade to output filters)
```

Comment: Deberias consultarlo con la gente de la plantilla.. poco podemos hacer sin el codigo...

Comment: Si estas con un FTP o si tenes algun tipo de acceso a los archivos ingresa para buscar en tu directorio raíz algún archivo llamado por ejemplo "ERROR_LOG" que no es mas que un archivo de texto donde van a quedar registrados los errores. Si podes pegar ese contenido aca o al menos las ultimas líneas seria de mucha utilidad.

Comment: "More information about this error may be available
in the server error log". prueba a revisar el error.log

Comment: agregue lo que me sale en ERROR_LOG

Comment: Es bastante probable que el módulo de seguridad ModSecurity esté dando un falso positivo porque interpreta que el contenido HTML que tu página genera es demasiado grande. Lo más recomendable es que lo trates con tu proveedor de hosting.